# Adding popup to table cell

Tags: javascript

I have a table and I want to show a popup from each cell. However I can not get my code to work. The code for popup makes the whole table disappear.

Here is the function for creating the table:

```
function(json) {
    var koosteRivi = ["Kaikki asiakkaat"];
    var html="<table id ='lasku'>";
    html+="<thead>";
    html+="<tr>";
    for(var i=0;i<json.vuosi[0].length;i++) {
        var cell=json.vuosi[0][i];
        html+="<th class=\"yla otsikko\">";
        html+=cell;
        html+="</th>";
        koosteRivi.push(0);
    }
    html+="<th class=\"yla otsikko\">";
    html+="Koko tilikausi";
    html+="</th>";
    html+="</tr>";
    html+="</thead>";
    for(var row=1;row<json.vuosi.length;row++) {
        var yht = 0;
        if(row%2 == 0) {
            html+="<tr>";
        } else {
            html+="<tr id =\"jokatoinen\">";
        }
        html+="<td>";
        html+=json.vuosi[row][0];
        html+="</td>";
        for(var i=1;i<json.vuosi[row].length;i++) {
            var asiakasKkCell=json.vuosi[row][i];
            koosteRivi[i]+=asiakasKkCell;
            html+="<td>";
            html+=formatSum(parseFloat(asiakasKkCell),","," ",CURRENCY);
            html+="</td>";
            yht+=parseFloat(asiakasKkCell);
        }
        html+="<th class=\"otsikko\">";
        html+=formatSum(yht,","," ",CURRENCY);
        html+="</th>";
        html+="</tr>";
    }
    html+="<tr>";
    html+="<th class=\"ala otsikko\">";
    html+=koosteRivi[0];
    html+="</th>";
    var lastCell=0;
    for(var i=1;i<koosteRivi.length-1;i++) {
        var cell=koosteRivi[i];
        html+="<th class=\"ala otsikko\">";
        html+=formatSum(parseFloat(cell),","," ",CURRENCY);
        html+="</th>";
        lastCell+=cell;
    }
    html+="<th class=\"ala otsikko\">";
    html+=formatSum(parseFloat(lastCell),","," ",CURRENCY);
    html+="</th>";
    html+="</tr>";
    html+="</table>";
    document.getElementById("as-invoicing-cumulYear").innerHTML=html;                               
}
```

And here is the code I use for creating the links:

```
function addRowHandlers() {

    var table = document.getElementById("lasku");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}

function createClickHandler(row){

    return function() { 
        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        var id = cell.innerHTML;
        alert("id:" + id);
    };

}

addRowHandlers();
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please format your code properly. As it was initially formatted, it was extremely difficult to read

Comment: Where is the code for popup? i just see an Alert from the ClickHandler ?

Comment: Alert is the popup. Once I get that working, I can fiddle with the popup more, so that it is not a simple popup-box